# Who cares if it takes 1,000 years for Sarlacc to digest you?

Tags: star-wars, jabba-the-hutt, sarlacc

C-3P0 informs Luke et al before they are thrown into the pit of Sarlacc that:

> "In its belly, you will find a new definition of pain and suffering as
>   you are slowly digested over a…thousand years."

Assuming you don't break your neck in the fall, surely you would:

1. Suffocate
2. Die of thirst
3. Starve
4. Die of old age

long before you were actually digested?

Comment: The implication is that the Sarlacc keeps you alive, presumably because you taste better that way or something.  Doesn't make a whole lot of sense from a thermodynamic standpoint, but hey, Star Wars physics.

Comment: I'd like to know how they found that out. Did someone leave a note for his many times great grandson - "cut that belly open on your fiftieth birthday and see if the victim we fed  to it 950 years ago is still alive and suffering"

Comment: @approachingdarknessfish: I don't think so, that question was about the workings of Sarlacc's biology, this is about the level of fear a would be meal should experience.

Comment: @Danny3414 carbon dating the poop? Actually, there’s a question- where does the sarlac excrete?

Comment: @user100501 - The proposed duplicate does actually answer the question; it indicates that the Sarlacc actually keeps its (intelligent) meals alive, and fed (dealing with the first three items in your list). Old age would still presumably come into play; the quoted text indicates that that actual duration of life depends on the species of the meal....

Comment: @user100501 - (Of course, if you modified the question to eliminate the other three concerns, you might still have a point. However, the pain and suffering involved lasting (say) 30 years vs. 1000 probably makes no difference to the meal.